# Grails one-to-many mapping with joinTable

Tags: grails, groovy, mapping, grails-orm

I have two domain-classes.  One is a "Partner" the other is a "Customer".  A customer can be a part of a Partner and a Partner can have 1 or more Customers:

```
class Customer {
    Integer id
    String name
    static hasOne = [partner:Partner]
    static mapping = {
        partner joinTable:[name:'PartnerMap',column:'partner_id',key:'customer_id']
    }
}

class Partner {
    Integer id
    static hasMany = [customers:Customer]
    static mapping = {
        customers joinTable:[name:'PartnerMap',column:'customer_id',key:'partner_id']
    }
}
```

However, whenever I try to see if a customer is a part of a partner, like this:

```
def customers = Customer.list()
customers.each {
     if (it.partner) {
          println "Partner!"
     }
}
```

I get the following error:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not execute query; SQL [select this_.customer_id as customer1_162_0_, this_.company as company162_0_, this_.display_name as display3_162_0_, this_.parent_customer_id as parent4_162_0_, this_.partner_id as partner5_162_0_, this_.server_id as server6_162_0_, this_.status as status162_0_, this_.vertical_market as vertical8_162_0_ from Customer this_]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query
```

It looks as if Grails is thinking partner_id is a part of the Customer query, and it's not... It is in the PartnerMap table, which is supposed to find the customer_id, then get the Partner from the corresponding partner_id.

Anyone have any clue what I'm doing wrong?

Edit:  I forgot to mention I'm doing this with legacy database tables.  So I have a Partner, Customer and PartnerMap table.  PartnerMap has simply a customer_id and partner_id field.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given the way 1-many works when you want a join table, I think it's not possible with standard GORM to make it bidirectional and access a Customer's Partner. But you can map the join table with a domain class and access things that way:

Customer:

```
class Customer {
   String name
   def getPartner() {
      PartnerMap.findByCustomer(this)?.partner
   }
}
```

Partner:

```
class Partner {
   String name
   def getCustomers() {
      PartnerMap.findAllByPartner(this)*.customer
   }
}
```

PartnerMap:

```
import org.apache.commons.lang.builder.HashCodeBuilder

class PartnerMap implements Serializable {

   Partner partner
   Customer customer

   boolean equals(other) {
      if (!(other instanceof PartnerMap)) {
         return false
      }

      other.partner?.id == partner?.id &&
         other.customer?.id == customer?.id
   }

   int hashCode() {
      def builder = new HashCodeBuilder()
      if (partner) builder.append(partner.id)
      if (customer) builder.append(customer.id)
      builder.toHashCode()
   }

   static PartnerMap get(long partnerId, long customerId) {
      find 'from PartnerMap where partner.id=:partnerId and customer.id=:customerId',
         [partnerId: partnerId, customerId: customerId]
   }

   static PartnerMap create(Partner partner, Customer customer, boolean flush = false) {
      new PartnerMap(partner: partner, customer: customer).save(flush: flush, insert: true)
   }

   static boolean remove(Partner partner, Customer customer, boolean flush = false) {
      PartnerMap instance = PartnerMap.findByPartnerAndCustomer(partner, customer)
      instance ? instance.delete(flush: flush) : false
   }

   static void removeAll(Partner partner) {
      executeUpdate 'DELETE FROM PartnerMap WHERE partner=:partner', [partner: partner]
   }

   static void removeAll(Customer customer) {
      executeUpdate 'DELETE FROM PartnerMap WHERE customer=:customer', [customer: customer]
   }

   static mapping = {
      id composite: ['customer', 'partner']
      version false
      table 'PartnerMap'
   }
}
```

Since you're not using hasMany, you lose the addToXXX dynamic method, but you can call `PartnerMap.create()` to relate two instances. You also lose the collection and back-ref in the domain classes, but I added utility methods for those.

Comment: Oops, I forgot to mention, I'm doing this with legacy database stuff... So I have to work with predefined tables.  I have a Customer, Partner and PartnerMap table.  PartnerMap is simply a customer_id and partner_id field.  Does this limit me?

Comment: I just realized this problem only exists when trying to load this stuff inside of the Grails console.  I have no clue why... I assumed the Grails console loaded up the environment appropriately sort of like Rails does...

Comment: I reworked the code but if it's working outside of the console then the simpler solution should be used. The console is very close to the Grails runtime environment, but there's a lot going on in run-app or when deployed in a war, and the console only approximates that environment.

Comment: Thanks for the help!  I just decided it was easier to write a dummy controller and write some quick test code in it to make sure my domain-classes were working as expected and they were.  It's a bummer that so much is required to just play with a domain-class that has a relationship inside of the grails console...